# How do I use a generator to initialize a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Code below:

```
def computerCost(x,y,theta):
    m = len(y)
    J = np.sum((np.dot(x,theta) - y)**2) /(2*m)
    return J

m = 100
x = np.linspace(-5,10,m)
y = np.linspace(1,100,m)
x, y = x.reshape(m,1), y.reshape(m,1)
theta_0 = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
theta_1 = np.linspace(-1,4,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(theta_0,theta_1)

###### Here I want to initialize a numpy array with generator.
J_vals = np.array(computerCost(x,y,np.array([a,b])) for a,b in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)) )

print('out:',J_vals)
```

Running this code in Python 3.5 gives:

```
out:<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000028ACF28B258>
```

The console prints that J_vals is a generator. Is there some way to change the generator into a `np.ndarrray`?

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are trying to solve? Maybe you can vectorize the operation, removing the need for `zip()` and `fromiter()`.

Comment: Inside your function you are doing `np.dot(x, theta)` where `x` is an array of shape `(100, 1)` and `theta` is of shape `(2,)`. This will not work. Can you try to explain the math you are trying to do here?

Comment: @NilsWerner You are right. I just want to use Least squares to draw a line model to fitting my data. And the computerCost function is to computer cost in one theta(matrix:[theta_0,theta_1])

Comment: See my answer on how to do it without the `for` loop and the `zip`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html).

Here's a simpler example to demonstrate how it works:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> np.fromiter((i + j for (i, j) in zip(a, b)), np.float)
array([ 5.,  7.,  9.])
```

Note you have to supply the data type as the second argument, and that the generator expression must be parenthesized since it's not the sole argument.

When I tried this with your sample code, I got an error saying shapes are not aligned... I'm guessing it's an issue with the dot product.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, I should change np.arrray([a,b]) in  J_vals = np.array(computerCost(x,y,np.array([a,b])) for a,b in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))   to np.array([[a,b]])  since the shape problem in dot product operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NumPy broadcasting to vectorize your operation, avoiding the need for Python loops altogether:

```
def computerCost(x, y, theta):
    return np.sum((x * theta - y) ** 2, axis=(0, 1)) / (2 * len(y))

m = 100
x = np.linspace(-5,10,m)[:, None, None]
y = np.linspace(1,100,m)[:, None, None]

theta_0 = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
theta_1 = np.linspace(-1,4,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(theta_0,theta_1)

XY = np.stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))[None, :, :]

computerCost(x, y, XY)
# array([ 7442.62878788,  7340.86628993,  7240.13955518, ...,  1322.02086831,
#         1320.72740104,  1320.46969697])
```

Comment: I want to know why  you add [:,None,Noe] in x = np.linspace(-5,10,m)[:, None, None], And why this operation can work well. @NilsWerner

Comment: You need to arrange your axes right for [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to work.